Should I use an alternate glue to affix furniture pads?
My home has a tiled floor and furniture with wooden legs. I need to move chairs and small tables almost daily. Dragging the furniture creates noise and risks scratching the tiles.
I’ve tried using adhesive 'furniture pads', but they only last a short time before slipping off. Despite thoroughly cleaning the surfaces with isopropyl alcohol and even sanding them lightly, the pads still don't stay in place. I've also tried different brands without success.
I suspect that the pre-applied reusable adhesive is too weak to handle the lateral forces. I'm considering using PVA or Polyurethane glue to attach the pads more permanently. Does anyone have experience with this? Will it work?

I am not interested in using pads which use mechanical fasteners. I can also not use sock style ones.

I had the same issue as you. Sock style worked for me. Why can't you use them?

@RMDman probably some kind of OCD about aesthetics. :)

@huesmann, that's my thought too.

Most furniture pads do not have a long life, they wear down from being moved.  Any glue you do use should be a type that is easy to remove/clean off.  Most glues/adhesives do not bond well to themselves or other glues.
